# C++ - Append text to a file with NTFS "append data" only permissions

Tags: c++, text, append, ntfs

I need to append some lines of text to a text-based log file. The file is hosted on a windows server and users can access via smb.

Domain users do not have write permission to the file, they only have "append text" permission.

The code below works but I cannot find how to put all the entries on different lines. All text appears on the same line.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
        return 0;
    //cout << argv[1] << "," << argv[2] << endl;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(argv[2], FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile,argv[1],strlen(argv[1]),0,0);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

I'd like do make the program ALWAYS add a new line character at the end of the text. I feel dumb but I cannot figure out how to work with the pointers to achieve my goal. =(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to writefile in new line in WIN32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514067/how-to-writefile-in-new-line-in-win32-api)

Answer (score 1):

Add a 2nd `WriteFile` before the `CloseHandle`.

```cpp
WriteFile(hFile, "\r\n", 2, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I was right to feel dumb. In my defense it was like 5AM in here...
Thank you very much!